# Cómo mostrar datos de columnas Foraneas de un solo usuario? MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Necesito saber como puedo mostrar en una pagina web, los datos almacenados en mi BD, los datos que quiero mostrar son la **habitación**, **piso**, **tipo**(habitacion), **id de la reserva** y el **nombre del usuario**, pero con mi consulta que esta abajo, solo me muestra todos los datos de "**reservas**". ¿Cómo puedo lograr mostrar de un solo usuario?

Esta es mi consulta:

```
select r.id, r.diaReserva, h.habitacion, h.tipo, h.piso, c.nombre
from reservas as r, hoteles as h, cuentas as c
where r.idHabitacion = h.idHotel
AND r.idCuenta = c.idCuenta
```

Esta son mis tablas:

```
create table cuentas(
idCuenta int not null auto_increment primary key,
user varchar(30),
pass varchar(30),
tipo varchar(1),
nombre varchar(30),
email varchar(30)
);

create table hoteles(
idHotel int not null auto_increment primary key,
habitacion varchar(30),
tipo varchar(30),
piso varchar(30),
cantidadCuarto int,
cantidadBano int,
cantidadCama int,
estado varchar(30)
);

create table reservas(
id int auto_increment not null,
diaReserva date not null,
idHabitacion int,
foreign key (idHabitacion) references hoteles (idHotel),
idCuenta int,
foreign key (idCuenta) references cuentas(idCuenta),
primary key (id)
);
```

Comment: Un hotel tiene una o más habitaciones, ¿verdad? Pero la tabla `hoteles` esta indicando que cada hotel tiene solamente una habitación. Te recomiendo que investigues sobre "Normalización de bases de datos".

Answer (score 1):

La consulta es correcta, sólo tiene el pequeño fallo de que los alias de las tablas no se asignan con 'as', esto se utiliza para asignar alias a un campo de búsqueda (pongo un ejemplo con el campo 'nombre'). Así debería funcionar:

```
select r.id, r.diaReserva, h.habitacion, h.tipo, h.piso, c.nombre as usuario
from reservas r, hoteles h, cuentas c
where r.idHabitacion = h.idHotel
and r.idCuenta = c.idCuenta
```

En este tipo de consulta el `join` entre tablas se hace en el momento de establecer las condiciones, mientras que si la query lleva el `join` explícito éste se realiza antes del where. En el segundo caso se pueden utilizar distintos tipos de [`join` o unión de tablas](https://www.dbasupport.com.mx/index.php/2-uncategorised/63-tipos-de-joins) según las necesidades de búsqueda.

```
select r.id, r.diaReserva, h.habitacion, h.tipo, h.piso, c.nombre
from reservas r
inner join hoteles h on r.idHabitacion = h.idHotel
inner join cuentas c on r.idCuenta = c.idCuenta
where r.idCuenta = 'identificador de usuario'
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando las uniones (tambien conocidos como `JOINs`) de `SQL`, que permiten combinar columnas de distintas tablas en una sola tabla, mediante algún campo en común (generalmente las claves primarias/foráneas).

```
SELECT r.id, h.habitacion, h.piso, h.tipo, c.nombre
FROM reservas r
INNER JOIN hoteles h ON r.idHabitacion = h.idHotel
INNER JOIN cuentas c ON r.idCuenta = c.IdCuenta
WHERE r.id = 1;
```